# Run find command on only local mount points

Tags: command-line, mount, find

I have a command to filter files with size  > 10 MB  but want to run it only on local mount points. Currently I have mounted some remote NFS in my system on `/nfs` so in my search I don't want to include this one.

The exact command I use is: `find . -type f -size +10M  -exec ls -ltrh {} \;`

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: I m using find command

Comment: Nfs mounted at /nfs mount point

Comment: @RegisteredUser - " find . -type f -size +10M  -exec ls -ltrh {} \; " this is the command I use to filter 10 M files but just dont want to include mount point named as /nfs and all its sub dir's.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `find` you can use the option (from `man find`):

```
-xdev  Don't descend directories on other filesystems.
```